# Loop from two ojbect from json

Tags: jquery, json

```js
$.each(data.bahan, function(i, v) {
  $("select.bahan_asli").clone().insertAfter("#bahan:last").val(v.id_bahan).addClass('duplicate').removeClass('bahan_asli').css("display", "block").append("<input type='hidden' value='" + data['detail'].id_detail + "'>");
}); //id_detail not from data.bahan, but it from data.detail
```

this json :

```
{
    "bahan": [{
        "id_bahan": "4",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }, {
        "id_bahan": "1",
        "nm_jenis": "katun"
    }],
    "detail": [{
        "id_detail": "5",
        "id_model": "3"
    }, {
        "id_detail": "6",
        "id_model": "3"
    }]
}
```

What the wrong code `data['detail'].id_detail` ? or how to loop two array `data['bahan']` and `data['detail']` in one loop use `.each` or another way ?

Comment: That's not [JSON](http://www.json.org), `data` is a [plain old object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object)

Answer (score 0):

You have a array so you need to loop

```
$.each(data.detail,function(i,v){
console.log(v.id_detail)
});
```

demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tb696pc9/

For your current setup you need to somehow change your json structure if you want to only loop based on **bahan**

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this to loop two array :

```
$.each([arr1, arr2], function() {
$.each(this, function(i, v) {
    // do something
});
});
```

alternate :

```
$.each( arr1.concat(arr2), function(i, v) {
$("p").append(v);
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZG4wq/2/)

Have tried using .each, still working on, here is the working code using 'for' loop in the mean time :

```
for (var i=0; i<json.bahan.length && json.detail.length; i++) {  
//alert("test");
alert("Data:" + json.bahan[i].id_bahan + " :" + json.bahan[i].nm_jenis);
alert("Data:" + json.detail[i].id_detail + ": " +  json.detail[i].id_model);
}
```

Comment: i think like $.each([arr1, arr2], function() {
$.each(this, function(i, v) {
    // do something
});
});

Comment: Second .each will take care of that, I used once for my requirement, worked fine, used .concat before, but performance wise i prefer .each(), hope you got the answer.

Comment: would you show how to access the array ?. example : `$.each([arr1, arr2], function() { $.each(this, function(i, v) { v[0].id_bahan or v[1].id_detail }); });` like it ?

Comment: can you give me example for `\\do something`

Answer (score 0):

data['detail'] is an array, not an object, so `data['detail'].id_detail` doesn't work, you would have to use something like `data['detail'][0].id_detail`, where 0 is the index you want.

If you want to look at the elements of both bahan and detail at the same time (ie look at the first element of bahan and the first element of detail, then look at the second element of bahan and the second element of detail, etc), you could use a basic for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.bahan.length && i < data.detail.length; i++) {
    console.log(data.bahan[i].id_bahan);
    console.log(data.bahan[i].nm_jenis);
    console.log(data.detail[i].id_detail);
    console.log(data.detail[i].id_model);
}
```

Would output:

```
4
katun
5
3
```

then

```
1
katun
6
3
```

Comment: Using 'for' for looping that too && operation. what if the first array in null ?